# Rails 5 not rendering JQuery result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I guess I did a mess with JQuery and my Rails practice, I intend to get two parameters from a 'form_tag' and then render a calculation result made in my controller inside a '' in a view, I get the result in the Network view (Chrome developer tools) but nothing is rendered in the . Here is the code related:
Route:

```
get '/calculator', to: 'users#bmi_calc'
```

users_controller.rb:

```
def bmi_calc
  bmi_table = {
  "Very severely underweight"             => { from: 0.0, to: 15.0 },
  "Severely underweight"                  => { from: 15.1, to: 16.0 },
  "Underweight"                           => { from: 16.1, to: 18.5 },
  "Normal (healthy weight)"               => { from: 18.51, to: 25.0 },
  "Overweight"                            => { from: 25.1, to: 30.0 },
  "Obese class I (moderately obese)"      => { from: 30.1, to: 35.0 },
  "Obese class II (severely obese)"       => { from: 35.1, to: 40.0 },
  "Obese class III (very severely obese)" => { from: 40.1, to: 60.0 },
  "Pure fat factor"                       => { from: 60.1, to: 100.0}
  }
  weight = params[:mass].to_f
  height = params[:height].to_f
  if weight > 0 && height > 0
    resultado = ''
    @bmi = weight / height ** 2
    bmi_table.each do |advice, range|
      if (@bmi > range[:from]) && (@bmi < range[:to])
        resultado = advice
      end
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: {resultado: resultado} }
    end
  else
    redirect_to current_user
  end
end
```

users.js.erb:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $("#calculator-img").click( function(){
    $.getJSON('/calculator', function(data) {
      var res = data.resultado;
      $("#bmi-result").html(res);
    });
  });
});
```

users/show.html.erb:

```
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section class="user_info">
      <h1><%= @user.name %></h1>
    </section>
    <section class="bmi_form">
      <%= render 'bmi_form' %>
    </section>

    <div id="bmi-result">

    </div>
  </aside>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <section class="mid_section">
      <p>Some text</p>
      <h2>BMI standard table</h2>
      <%= image_tag "BMItable.png", alt: "BMI stardard table" %>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

_bmi_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag calculator_path, method: "get", remote: true, class: "navbar-left" do %>
  <%= label_tag :mass, "Your mass (weight) in Kg" %>
  <%= number_field_tag :mass, params[:mass], step: 0.01, class: "form-control" %>

  <%= label_tag :height, "Your height in meters" %>
  <%= number_field_tag :height, params[:height], step: 0.01, class: "form-control" %>

  <%= image_submit_tag("BMI.gif", id: "calculator-img") %>
<% end %>
```

And finally this is what I get in the Chrome developers tools:

[image: Chrome dev tools]

Plese help me understand what I am doing wrong. Thanks
(This is the challenge I intended to solve: https://gist.github.com/JonaMX/d29a754ae625664b0cf7
In the end I delivered but I had to render a new page with the result... Not pretty at all)

Comment: First check if your JavaScript runs. Set a `console.log("Something");` or `alert("Something")`. You've set the form, to `remote: true`, which means an ajax request is also done just by pressing the *submit*, not only by the *onclick* event. This is also visible in the request header. If `Accept=application/json` than it is done by your JSON request. If Rails handles it with the `remote: true` event, I believe it is requesting `Accept=application/javascript`, but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind a handler function to your form's ajax request. 
First add an id to your form:

```
<%= form_tag calculator_path, method: "get", remote: true, class: "navbar-left", id: "bmi-form" do %>
  <%= label_tag :mass, "Your mass (weight) in Kg" %>
  <%= number_field_tag :mass, params[:mass], step: 0.01, class: "form-control" %>

  <%= label_tag :height, "Your height in meters" %>
  <%= number_field_tag :height, params[:height], step: 0.01, class: "form-control" %>

  <%= image_submit_tag("BMI.gif", id: "calculator-img") %>
<% end %>
```

Then change your javascript to something like this:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $("#bmi-form").on( "ajax:success", function(evt, data, status, xhr){
    var res = data.resultado;
    $("#bmi-result").html(res);
  });
});
```

For more information see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Answer (score 0):

Can try once this code

```
$(document).ready( function(){
      $("#calculator-img").click( function(){
          $.getJSON('/calculator', function(data) {
              var res = $.parseJSON(data);
              $("#bmi-result").html(res.resultado);
          });
      });
   });
```

For more information see https://boxoverflow.com/get-json-jquery-ajax/